# How to enable Hibernate Bytecode enhancement in gradle

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, gradle

How to enable the plugin with gradle? Unfortunately it's not working for me with the current setup:

build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.hibernate.orm") version "5.4.17.Final"
}

tasks.withType<org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.EnhanceTask>().configureEach {
    options.enableLazyInitialization = true
    options.enableDirtyTracking = true
    options.enableAssociationManagement = true
}
```

settings.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.hibernate.orm") {
                useModule("org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if its working or not, how can I check if the plugin is enabled? There is no console output or something like that. Also some features are not working which SHOULD work when the plugin is setted up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a nice way to resolve the plugin dependency!

Here is what I believe the correct way to configure the plugin using Kotlin DSL

```
hibernate {
    enhance(closureOf<org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.EnhanceExtension> {
        enableLazyInitialization = true
        enableDirtyTracking = true
        enableAssociationManagement = true
        enableExtendedEnhancement = false
    })
}
```

This should work well on Java code, but not always on Kotlin on incremental builds. You must also need to have Java source set to trigger the instrument.

Comment: For me it did not change the compiled classes in any way... (5.6.0-Final)

Answer (score 4):

As of Hibernate `6.x`, the gradle configuration looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.hibernate.orm' version '6.1.7.Final'
}

hibernate {
    enhancement {
        lazyInitialization true
        dirtyTracking true
        associationManagement true
        extendedEnhancement true
    }
}
```

The `settings.gradle` file doesn't need the `hibernate-gradle-plugin` resolution strategy.

As of `6.2`, `enableLazyInitialization` and `enabledDirtyTracking` will be `true` **by default** and **deprecated** at the same time as documented in [this migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#enhancement).